# How to Add Multiple Users Authorization in FastAPI?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt, swagger, fastapi

I want to add two types of users in my FastAPI application. I want to explain the scenario first. Please read...

It's a school note sharing platform. There are two types of users, teachers and students. They all will have different kinds of work. Like teachers can post notes and students can read those notes. And for that students have to be authorized and also the same for the teachers to post notes and to update or delete those notes.

How I can do this?

I've tried to do this. But the Swagger UI is showing me only one authorization. Like only for the students. Whenever I'm clicking on the lock button near the teachers route, it's showing me the same popup login window with tokenUrl = students/token for both of the users.

I want to two tokenUrl for two types of users.

1. teachers (tokenUrl=teachers/token)
2. students (tokenUrl=students/token)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to create a tokenUrl for every role, imagine you have multiple roles how would you manage it? you can't follow this approach since the 2 user type will log in to the same platform.
following the best practices, create a role table in your database and then when create the user give it a role, when a user logs in you will pass the role in the JWT so you can use it later to verify who's logging in.
this approach will give you flexibility to manage many roles and make your project easy to scale when you want to add many roles like for administrations stuff.
this is an example of the data that JWT will have :

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": user.id,
        "email": user.email
    },
    "role": {
        "id": role.id,
        "name": role.name,
    },
}
```

then just a create a function to verify the role in the token passed to your endpoint.
check documentation for further understanding: [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/)